# ubuntu performance from live usb is extremely slow

Tags: live-usb, huawei

I have created live usb with ventoy (rufus as well) and when running "Try Ubuntu or Install" option it appears to be extremely slow, i.e. on UI mouse is barely moving, as well as navigating from keyboard.

I am running this with USB 3.2 stick on Huawei Matebook B7 (i7, 16gb, ssd) via USB-USBc adapter since this laptop doesn't have any ports other than usb-c. I have tested its speed when loading .iso file to that usb on this machine from Windows explorer and speed is looks good (80Mb/s)

I have tried using same stick on my very old laptop and it loads Ubuntu shell nice and smooth and without issues.

What could be an issue?

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; thus no-one currently could reasonably answer. You mention different hardware, thus you may have selected a *software stack* (*ie. release & kernel stack choice if you're using a LTS release; you didn't give details*) that better suits one device when compared to the other, but you gave no specifics.

Comment: @guiverc, it could possibly help, but would be reasonble to assume people are downloading latest stable, e.g. 22.04

Comment: You mention *latest stable* which currently is Ubuntu 23.04; your question relates to 22.04 you've not mentioned which was three *stable* releases ago, even if the latest *LTS*, it's far from *latest stable*.  ISOs vary also on release; so if booting an ISO that is later than Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (ie. 22.10 & later) there are differences as work is made to ensure all architectures boot the same for a given release, not that the ISO boots identically to prior releases (*which was a safe assumption up to 20.04*).  The differences between releases can influence speed for some hardware significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue happened to me, I was installing the new lunar Ubuntu on a machine with NVIDIA GPU it was a Ge-force gaming GPU. For some reason, the computer CPU fan was sniping fast and the computer was slow which I didn't understand why because it has very powerful specs.

I selected the "Safe graphics" option. the installation was slow but it worked. I then disabled Snap as soon as I checked system monitor and everything worked fine after that. for some reason, snap was using up all the computer resources and the Ethernet adapter it also was filling up the var/logs file. believe it or not the logs file reached the size of 300gb in a matter of an hour

Comment: yes, you are right that selecting Safe graphics option from boot menu resolves performance issues with UI. Super, thanks

Comment: For reference: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/problems-with-intel-iris-xe-gpu-hardware-video-acceleration-in-22-04/34849